Display how many items are inside overflow
Hello i am trying to achieve something like this:
Desired result
In this case i want to pass list of strings and render them in maximum of 2 rows and if rest of items in list does not fit in this and are hidden in overflow i would like know the count of these items. The component also can have any kind of fontSize.
I made something like this but my problem is that i cant hide the triple dots because of css properties i am using which are like this:
    whiteSpace: 'normal',
    display: '-webkit-box',
    WebkitLineClamp: 2,
    WebkitBoxOrient: 'vertical',

My component looks like this currently. I'ts a bit hacky as the counter is using position absolute, ideally i don't want that and to render the counter exactly of the place where triple dots are.
I have this code currently:
const textList = ['SNOW', 'DDOG', 'MDB', 'DOCN', 'VMW', 'NVDA', 'AMZN', 'AMD', 'QCOM', 'TSM', 'AVGO', 'INTC', 'ASML', 'AMAT', 'MU', 'SWKS']
  const containerRef=useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)
  const [invisible,setInvisible]=useState<string[]>([])

  useEffect(() => {
    const element = containerRef?.current as HTMLDivElement
    const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver((el: ResizeObserverEntry[]) => {
      const container = el[0].target.getBoundingClientRect()

      const spans = textList.map((_, index) => {
        const span = containerRef.current?.querySelector(`span:nth-child(${index + 1})`);
        const coords = span?.getBoundingClientRect()
        return { name:span?.textContent || '',isVisible:coords ? coords.bottom < container.bottom : null }
      });

      const invisibleItems= spans
        .filter(i=>i && !i.isVisible && i.name)
        .map(i=>i?.name?.replace(', ',''))

      setInvisible(invisibleItems)
    });

    element && resizeObserver.observe(element);
    return () => {
      resizeObserver.disconnect()
    };
  }, [containerRef]);

 return <Box gap={4} sx={{ padding: '12px 35px 0px 22px' }}>
          <Box>
            <Typography variant="inherit" maxLines={1}>
              Multi watchlist
            </Typography>
            <Tooltip title={invisible.length ?textList.join(', '):''} placement="top">
                <Typography maxLines={2} variant="h5" fontWeight={900} sx={{ cursor:invisible.length ? 'Pointer' : undefined }}>
                  <ContainerBox ref={containerRef}>
                  {textList.map((txt,index) => <span key={txt + '-gsa'}>{index === textList.length-1 ? txt : `${txt}, `} </span>)}
                  {invisible.length ? <div style={{ position: 'absolute', right:-15,bottom:0 }}>+{invisible.length}</div> : null}
                  </ContainerBox>
                </Typography>
            </Tooltip>
          </Box>
        </Box>

I was also trying to do some logic around flexbox but couldn't track when elements wrap after 2nd row.
Mine looks like this:
My result

Use a fixed-width font and count the characters. That is, know ahead of time the space to be consumed.

Issue is that also i can't have fixed width or font size :\

Courier is an example of fixed width. You wouldnt be able to use it?

Just to be clear, regarding the font-size - all your "tags", or whatever you want to call them, will always have the same size, within this component, yes? And you just need this to work independently of whether you set the font-size for the whole component to 16px, 2em or 1.5rem, right?

Each tag will have same font size but i want that the component is generic/reusable so i can f.ex pass from props fontSize (which will affect all items in the list so all will have same fontSize). Also the text length of these tags can be anything
